# PHP Syntax Error. Cant Seem to Find Fix

Tags: php, syntax

Can anyone point out how to fix the 2 Syntax Errors I am getting? I am not very advanced with PHP.

Here is the Code:

```
$code = '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        <table id="slideleft" style=" overflow:auto; position:fixed; top:25%;"><tr class="slideLeftItem" style="position:fixed;left:-320px;z-index:1000;height:100%;"><td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GMJe-Am-U9Q/T4p4bZu7jDI/AAAAAAAAAFs/qQqmMGn-wwg/s800/facebook-vertical.png" style="top:5px; position:absolute; border-left-width:5px; left:318px;"/></td><td class="contentBox" style="border:solid 5px #5370AD; width:300px;height:300px;position:relative;border-radius:5px;background-color:white;"><div id="fb-root"></div><script type="text/javascript" >(function() {var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);());</script>

       <fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/ExplicitWebsiteDesign?ref=hl" width="300" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box></td></tr></table><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(".slideLeftItem").append('<div style="font-size:12px;font-family: arial;width:300px;text-align:right;"><a rel="dofollow" href="http://techbrij.com/944/add-social-slider-widget-website" style="background-color:#D2C9CA;padding:3px 7px;font-weight:bold;color:#516FA9">Get This Widget</a></div>');jQuery("#slideleft tr").hover(function(b){var a=jQuery(this);jQuery("#slideleft tr").not(a).hide();a.css({"z-index":"9999"});a.stop().animate({left:0})},function(b){var a=jQuery(this);a.css({"z-index":"1000"});a.stop().animate({left:-a.outerWidth()});jQuery("#slideleft tr").show()});</script>}</script>';
```

And image below is a screenshot to my code... Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you read this code ? I can't.

Comment: there are so many syntax errors also!

Comment: What are the syntax errors? And are you sure they are PHP errors and not JS?

Comment: ![In the above image I described the problem as best as I can!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pLlx8.png) In the above image I described the problem as best as I can!

Answer (score 2):

```
$code = ' (function() {var e = document.createElement('scr
```

You are trying to save the js as string but you have ' in your js code. That messes it up. You just need to escape those single quotes. Change the ones inside the main one from ' to \'. This should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

try using [output buffer](http://hk.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to your advantage:

```
ob_start();
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        <table id="slideleft" style=" overflow:auto; position:fixed; top:25%;"><tr class="slideLeftItem" style="position:fixed;left:-320px;z-index:1000;height:100%;"><td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GMJe-Am-U9Q/T4p4bZu7jDI/AAAAAAAAAFs/qQqmMGn-wwg/s800/facebook-vertical.png" style="top:5px; position:absolute; border-left-width:5px; left:318px;"/></td><td class="contentBox" style="border:solid 5px #5370AD; width:300px;height:300px;position:relative;border-radius:5px;background-color:white;"><div id="fb-root"></div><script type="text/javascript" >(function() {var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);());</script>

       <fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/ExplicitWebsiteDesign?ref=hl" width="300" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box></td></tr></table><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(".slideLeftItem").append('<div style="font-size:12px;font-family: arial;width:300px;text-align:right;"><a rel="dofollow" href="http://techbrij.com/944/add-social-slider-widget-website" style="background-color:#D2C9CA;padding:3px 7px;font-weight:bold;color:#516FA9">Get This Widget</a></div>');jQuery("#slideleft tr").hover(function(b){var a=jQuery(this);jQuery("#slideleft tr").not(a).hide();a.css({"z-index":"9999"});a.stop().animate({left:0})},function(b){var a=jQuery(this);a.css({"z-index":"1000"});a.stop().animate({left:-a.outerWidth()});jQuery("#slideleft tr").show()});</script>}</script>
<?php
$code = ob_get_clean();
```